# Plugin external .dll reference with local-copy false but .dll in different location on users machine

Tags: .net, dll, wix, shared-libraries

I have developed a plugin for an application.  The developer documentation for this application requires that the API file, let's call it `API.dll`, should be `copy-local = false` when referenced in my plugin, `MyPlugin.dll`.  To do otherwise, to quote from the documentation, "will create problems".

The problem is that I cannot guarantee that the installation directory of `API.dll` on users machines will match that of my machine.  Therefore the reference will be broken.  Also `API.dll` would not be expected to be registered in the GAC.

My thoughts on a possible solution is to modify the installer (it's built using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) ) for my plugin to sniff out the `API.dll` installation directory on the user's machine (or prompt them to select it).  Then the installer would need to amend the external reference within `MyPlugin.dll` to point at `API.dll` directory.

My query is two fold:

- Is the above a sensible approach to this problem?

and if so

- How do I amend an external reference of my compiled .Net `MyPlugin.dll` file with an installer?